Password protect a directory, without using encryption, compression, or permissions
As laid out to me:

No encryption, because of possible use in on Windows also (so this folder will be in an NTFS partition).

No compression so the user can easily navigate and move files in and out without having to do "something special" (like click through menus).

No permissions, because user may have to use this drive on other computers (that will likely be Windows).

No separate Linux accounts/profiles to separate the data, because the drive itself must be removable.


The base idea is that user has a Linux setup, but will need a folder that has a very simple password protection for Linux.
The "Threat Actor"? The user's 7 year old, who isn't computer savvy, but will (and has) deleted important files in the past. The user does not have the money to buy another computer for the child.
I've separated the partition with the directory in question on a separate hard drive and symlinked the current installed OS to it for ease of access for the user, but don't know how to simple password protect the directory like in Windows.
Also, bonus kudos if the solution will work across the major Linux distributions (Arch-based, Debian-based, Fedora-based, etc.)--that way, no matter which distro the user decides to try out next, it'll work. (User is considering Nobara--currently on Netrunner).
I've looked at these and their solutions involved encryption:
Simplest way to password protect a directory and its contents without having to create new files?
How to create a password-protected folder in Linux server?
Creating password protected folders inside password protected samba share

With all the extra requirements (including "portable to Windows") I don't think this can be done ...

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I wonder you need a backup & restore program, not password protect.

There is no software that can satisfy your requirements.
The NTFS filesystem does not provide the 'hooks' that any complex Linux protection requires, to be able trap open calls, and send them off to the protection scheme.
You haven't condidered the context that the process doing the open has (STDOUT, STDERR, @ENV, etc). How does the protection scheme that trapped the open find who to prompt?
Are you going to limit the rate at which prompts are issued, or deal with hundreds per second?
